# GetElementsByTagNames and block display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a "long read" article, using HTML, CSS and JavaScript, I would like to improve the navigation throughout the text by adding a "table of contents". It may seems strange, but I wish I could just do so by hiding every content wrapped within div tags when clicking on a title (h1, h2, h3 ...). Thus, only the titles would remain displayed on the page, one after another, it would look like a fancy table of contents. Since I'm new to programming, I'm learning on the fly. Finding a proper way to do so is not obvious to me at the moment.

Here's what I'm using within a header tag.

```
<h1 onclick="ff('hide');">
```

And here's a very simple JS "flipflop" function, only working with one single identified element, off course.

```
function ff(id)
{
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none")
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    else    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

How could I make that function works for every div tags of a document ? I'm trying to use getElementsByClass or getElementsByTagName methods, but I don't know how to make them work properly since it's working with arrays...

Any help would be appreciated. This is the first time I'm using this website, I hope I'm sticking to the rules accordingly. Since I'm not a good english speaker, I would also appreciate any links to a solution that could show me a relevant way to go.

Many thanks to you !

Comment: So to be clear - if they click _any_ heading, then _all_ the divs will disappear. Then if they click any heading again, all divs will be made visible once more?

Comment: By the way, welcome to SO. Your question is a good one, and mostly clear :)

Comment: If you use `node.style.display = ''` the node will return to its original value. As `node.style.display` starts as blank I find it more logical to work like that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this, clicking on first element (toggle)

```
<h1 onclick="ff('toHide');">toggle</h1>

<h1 class="toHide">hide</h1>

<h1>not hide</h1>

<h1 class="toHide">hide</h1>
```

Just to be clear, i've made a fiddle but this code seems to work only if tested in my browser. Have no idea why

```
function ff(c) {
    //get array
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName(c);
    //single element
    var el = "";

    //loop through your collection
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        el = arr[i];
        //the function
        if (el.style.display == "none") {
            el.style.display = "block"; 
        }else {
            el.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers ! The code you've provided works perfectly ! It looks cool now :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you found this answer useful you can set it as "accepted" and get me some reputation. Have a nice day :)

Comment: It's done, thanks again. It took me some time to find out how to do so ^^